# Change Korn prompt to show shorter path for working directory

Tags: prompt, ksh

I have changed my `.kshrc` to show my prompt as follows:
`511 /export/home/students/cninja $` where `511` is the command number and `../students/cninja` is the current working directory.

Is it possible to show a shortened version of the working directory, the prompt then showing something like: `511 ~/cninja $` or `511 ../students/cninja $` or what have you?

This is what my line looks like in `.kshrc`:

`PS1=' ! $PWD $'; export PS1`

---

**Update:** I haven't been able to determine whether I have a ksh88 or ksh93 shell.  Most of the `echo *what have you*` commands return a blank stare and a prompt from the shell, and `echo ${.sh.version}` returns `/bin/ksh: ${.sh.version}:  bad substitution`.

Comment: What OS are you running? `uname -a`

Comment: `SunOS solaris 5.10 Generic_141445-09 i86pc i386 i86pc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exist a few implementations of ksh:

- The original (or AT&T) one by David Korn with two major variants (ksh88 and ksh93) each one having different versions with a different feature set
- `pdksh` (the public-domain Korn shell) with a few derivatives.
- `zsh`. Zsh has a ksh emulation mode which it activates when called as `ksh`.

You may want to use zsh as your ksh, or even switch altogether to zsh which is a much more powerful tool as an interactive shell.

If you call zsh as `ksh`. You can have the prompt expansion you want by doing (add it to your `$ENV` file):

```
setopt PROMPT_PERCENT # restore zsh prompt expansion disabled by the ksh mode
PS1='%! %~$ '
```

Otherwise, if you do need to stick with the AT&T or PD ones, you could aproximate it with:

```
PS1='! $(pwd | sed "s,^$HOME,~,")$ '
```

Which would work for `~` but not for `~other-user`.

Example:

```
$ echo ${.sh.version}
Version JM 93u+ 2012-02-29
$ PS1='! $(pwd | sed "s,^$HOME,~,")$ '
85 ~$ cd /tmp
86 /tmp$ cd
87 ~$
```

From a vague recollection from decades ago, it could be that ksh88 doesn't expand command substitutions inside `$PS1`. In that case, you could still use some trick like:

```
one=1
tilde='~'
PS1='! ${tilde[0${one#${PWD##"$HOME"*}1}]}${PWD#"$HOME"}$ '
```

(which I've now verified works on all of ksh93u+ on Debian, ksh88i on Solaris, MirBSD ksh 40.9.20120630 (pdksh derivative) on Debian, and zsh 4.3.17 (when called as `ksh`) on Debian, so I'd be surprised if there was any ksh where it didn't work)

The idea being that if `$PWD` starts with `$HOME`, then `${PWD##"$HOME"*}` is empty, so `${one#1}` is empty, so we get `${tilde[0]}` that is `$tilde`. But if it doesn't then `${PWD##"$HOME"*}` is `$PWD`, then `${one#${PWD}1}` is `$one`, so we get `${tilde[1]}` which is empty as the `$tilde` array as only one element.

Comment: I may be missing something, but I tried `PS1='! $(pwd | sed "s,^$HOME,~,")$ '` and it didn't work.

Comment: In which way does it not work? What version/implementation of ksh?

Comment: It changed the prompt to `(pwd | sed "s,^$HOME,~,")$ '`, basically.  I get bad substitution with this `echo ${.sh.version}`.  Is there another way to find the version?  Sorry that my n00b is showing.

Comment: It should be `$(pwd...)` (with `$`). What effect do you get? If it's pdksh, you may look at `echo "$KSH_VERSION"`. Or you can try `what /bin/ksh`.

Comment: It changed it to `667 $(pwd | sed s,^/export/home/students/cninja,~,)$`

Comment: I think you have an old ksh88. Presumably you're using some commercial Unix. I've edited my answer with a trick for ksh88.

Comment: I've tried your edit and that didn't work, either.  Teacher's `.kshrc` says `PS1='!  ${pwd#$HOME} $ '; export PS1`, which only gives me the command number and `$`.

Comment: That would be `${PWD`, not `${pwd`. That would leave off the `$HOME` in `$PWD`, but not replace it with a `~`. What system are you on? Is that Solaris?

Comment: Yes sir, Solaris 5.10.  I tried it with `${PWD` and I just get the command number.

Comment: I managed to get hold of a Solaris 10 machine and the solution I posted for ksh88 does work there with /ust/bin/ksh (the one starting with "one=1").

Answer (score 3):

I thought the following would work, but it turned out to be a bash specific solution. Leaving this answer for reference purpose.

```
export PS1=' ! $( basename $PWD )'
```

Maybe it requires backtics instead of the `$( )` construct.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `basename`.  Would that be `/export`?

Comment: no, basename is a shell command  that returns the last 'part' of the $PWD.

Comment: OIC!  I will try it again, then.

Comment: It didn't work.  I tried `PS1=' ! $( basename $PWD )'` and PS1=' ! ` basename $PWD ` '

Comment: My trick must be bash specific then. Bash and ksh are pretty much alike, but not identical.

Comment: One of the first things I tried was `\w`.  :)  Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Korn Shell "discipline function" (basically a getter/setter) to wrangle the path into the form you want:

```
function RELATIVE_PWD.get {
    if [ "${PWD:0:${#HOME}}" = "$HOME" ]
    then
            .sh.value="~${PWD:${#HOME}}"
    else
            .sh.value="$PWD"
    fi
}
PS1='! ${RELATIVE_PWD} \$ '
```

Tested on ksh93.  Not sure if it works on ksh88.

Comment: Didn't know about this construct. I only care about the current dir name, so my variation looks like this: `function PS1PWD.get { [ "${PWD}" == "${HOME}" ] && .sh.value="~" || .sh.value="${PWD##*/}"; }` and include `${PS1PWD}` in my prompt.

Answer (score 0):

```
UserLoc=$(for user_loc in $(egrep -v "root|shutdown|halt|nologin" /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{print $1}' ); do echo -e "$user_loc"; done | grep $USER)

# User shell
MYSHELL=$(echo $SHELL | awk -F/ '{print $NF}')
if [ "$MYSHELL" == "bash" ] ; then
        Default=$(echo -e "\e[00m")
        Black=$(echo -e "\e[30m")
        Red=$(echo -e "\e[31m")
        Green=$(echo -e "\e[32m")
        Orange=$(echo -e "\e[33m")
        Blue=$(echo -e "\e[34m")
        Magenta=$(echo -e "\e[35m")
        Cyan=$(echo -e "\e[36m")
        White=$(echo -e "\e[37m")
        Def=$(echo -e "\e[0;0m")
        Bold=$(echo -e "\e[1m")
        Under=$(echo -e "\e[4m")
        Normal=$(tput sgr0)
        PrtF="$"
        PS1='[${Color}${USER}${Default}@${Hostname}] \W ${PrtF} '
elif [ "$MYSHELL" == "ksh" ] ; then
        esc="\033["
        Default=$(echo -e "${esc}00m")
        Black=$(echo -e "${esc}30m")
        Red=$(echo -e "${esc}31m")
        Green=$(echo -e "${esc}32m")
        Orange=$(echo -e "${esc}33m")
        Blue=$(echo -e "${esc}34m")
        Magenta=$(echo -e "${esc}35m")
        Cyan=$(echo -e "${esc}36m")
        White=$(echo -e "${esc}37m")
        Def=$(echo -e "${esc}0m")
        Bold=$(echo -e "${esc}1m")
        Under=$(echo -e "${esc}4m")
        PrtF="$"
        PS1='[${Color}${USER}${Default}@${Hostname}] $(if [ "${PWD#$HOME}" != "$PWD" ];then print "~${PWD#$HOME}"; else print "$(basename $PWD)"; fi) ${PrtF} '
else
        PS1="[\u@\h] \w \\$ "
fi

# Color for login's user
# if root or admin user => Red
if [ "$EUID" -eq 0 ] ; then
    Color=${Red}${bold}
        PrtF="#"
# if user local => Cyan
elif [ "$UserLoc" == "$USER"  ] ; then
    Color=${Cyan}${bold}
# if standard user (AD or LDAP) => green
else
   Color=${Green}${bold}
fi

export PS1
```